# Немогу сравнять елементы на одном уровне

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Здраствуйте, как мне сравнять елементы на одном уровне?

```html
            <div class="col-2 offset-md-10">     
                <label>Search by Name:</label>        
                <input class="form-control w-100 mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" />
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это неполная разметка. В текущем виде она работает корректно

Comment: Если надо, то инпут можно положить внутрь label

Comment: <div class="col offset-md-10">     
                <label>Search by Name: <input class="form-control w-100 mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" /></label>        
            </div>  
Если я правильно понял то вот так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="as-container p-4">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-auto row flex-nowrap align-items-baseline ms-sm-auto">
    <label class="col-auto pe-0">Search by Name:</label>
    <div class="col pe-0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Для теста адаптивности (с эмуляцией вьюпорта браузерными devtools), надо развернуть пример на всю страницу после его запуска.

---

Доки:

- [BS Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)
- [BS Spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: При использовании старого BS4, вместо `e` в именах классов утилит отступов надо использовать `r`, а вместо `s` - `l` (в данном случае). То есть, `ms``ml` и `pe``pr`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!